# Using - observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, swift3

I'm trying to convert a Swift 2.2 project to Swift 3, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Method 'observeValue(forKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:)' with Objective-C selector 'observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:' conflicts with method 'observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)' from superclass 'NSObject' with the same Objective-C selector" for the function call
```

On my function whose signature is:

```
func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, ofObject: Any?, change: [String : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)."
```

I have read the advice on the Swift 3 Migration Guide web site:

> "Workaround: Add an @objc(objectiveC:name:) attribute before the implementation of the optional requirement with the original Objective-C selector inside."

But it isn't clear to me how this is actually supposed to be applied in a source file, and nothing I have tried so far has worked successfully.

Can anyone explain how to set this up properly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just start typing `observeValueFor...` and `Xcode` will suggest you a valid autocompletion for that. Choose it, and you should be good to go.

Your function then should look something like this:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

Comment: It seems like the class this is in needs to be a subclass of NSObject.  Tried to do this in a singleton without subclassing NSObject and doesn't work.

Comment: @SunnyPatel yes, KVO works with NSObject subclasses only (actually with Objc runtime managed classes only).

Answer (score 18):

This is what (finally) worked for me using Swift 3.0 in Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a):

```
@objc
override open func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
```