# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' Swift 3

Tags: swift3

after updating to Swift 3 a lot of places I getting this error I have change the place of ? and ! but another error appeared (Type [String : AnyObject]? Has not subscript members)

```
  func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
        if !didFindMyLocation {
            let myLocation: CLLocation = change? [NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation //Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
            viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
            viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true

            didFindMyLocation = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using - observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136706/using-observevalueforkeypathofobjectchangecontext-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would have added `override` you would get the first hint that the method *does not override any method from its superclass*.

The signature has been changed to

```
func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, 
                           of object: Any?, 
                              change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, 
                             context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

Comment: thanks that worked fine @vadian do you know answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673705/xcodeproj-file-within-xcworkspace-created-through-cocoa-pods-is-disabled

Comment: No, I would remove all pods and recreate them.

Comment: Thanks I have done that but all the files have gone in the folders I made xcode